# DBeaver Denodo data access issue: 'user does not have EXECUTE privileges'

Tags: database, dbeaver, denodo

I am managing to connect to data in my organisation via Denodo Design Studio fine, but when I try to do it through DBeaver, I get the following error: `SQL Error [20100] [HY000]: The user does not have EXECUTE privileges on the view XXXX`

Any idea where I should look to fix this? I am just doing a simple SELCT * FROM XXXX table query for a small table.

I also have no issues connecting to the database, and can navigate the schemas and see the table/view names.

Using Denodo denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver-8.0-update-20220815 via the DBeaver Denodo connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are encountering an issue while trying to connect to data via DBeaver. The error message "SQL Error [20100] [HY000]: The user does not have EXECUTE privileges on the view XXXX" indicates that the user account you are using to connect to the Denodo server through DBeaver may not have the necessary EXECUTE privileges on the view you are trying to access.

To resolve this, one possible solution is to check the permissions for the user account. Ensure that the user account has the required EXECUTE privileges on the specific view. You can do this by logging into the Denodo server using the Denodo Design Studio or administration tool and verifying the permissions for the user account.

Another aspect to consider is the version of the Denodo JDBC driver you are using. According to the Denodo Community, it's essential to use the JDBC driver of an update that matches or is older than the update installed in the Denodo server you are connecting to. For example, if you are connecting to a Denodo server version 8.0 update 20210715, you should use the JDBC driver included in that update or an older update.

For further assistance and previous discussions related to this issue, you can find more details on the Denodo Community forum at this link: [DBeaver data access issue](https://community.denodo.com/answers/question/details?questionId=906Du00000000gTIAQ&title=DBeaver+data+access+issue).

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are right. I had to speak to my data admin to give me the privelages.